# NSKeyedArchiver fails with CLLocationCoordinate2D structs. Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nskeyedarchiver

I don't understand why I can archive `CGPoint` structs but not `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs.  What's the difference to the archiver?

Platform is iOS.  I'm running in the simulator and haven't tried on the device.

```
// why does this work:
NSMutableArray *points = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(10, 11);
[points addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes: &p objCType: @encode(CGPoint)]];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:points toFile: @"/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/points.bin" ];

// and this doesnt work:
NSMutableArray *coords = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
CLLocationCoordinate2D c = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(121, 41);
[coords addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes: &c objCType: @encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)]];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:coords toFile: @"/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/coords.bin" ];
```

I get a crash on the 2nd `archiveRootObject` and this message is printed to the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedArchiver encodeValueOfObjCType:at:]: this archiver cannot encode structs'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, Tom, are you ready for some geek-ness?  I'm an "older" guy in this world of young whippersnappers.  However, I remember a few things about C, and I'm just a geek at heart.

Anyway, there is a subtle difference between this:

```
typedef struct { double d1, d2; } Foo1;
```

and this:

```
typedef struct Foo2 { double d1, d2; } Foo2;
```

The first is a type alias to an anonymous structure.  The second is a type alias to `struct Foo2`.

Now, the documentation for `@encode` says that the following:

```
typedef struct example {
    id   anObject;
    char *aString;
    int  anInt;
} Example;
```

will result in `{example=@*i}` for both `@encode(example)` or `@encode(Example)`.  So, this implies that `@encode` is using the actual struct tag.  In the case of a typedef that creates an alias to an anonymous struct, it looks like `@encode` always returns `?`'

Check this out:

```
NSLog(@"Foo1: %s", @encode(Foo1));
NSLog(@"Foo2: %s", @encode(Foo2));
```

Anyway, can you guess how CLLocationCoordinate2D is defined?  Yep.  You guessed it.

```
typedef struct {
CLLocationDegrees latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

I think you should file a bug report on this.  Either `@encode` is broken because it does not use alias typedefs to anonymous structs, or CLLocationCoordinate2D needs to be fully typed so it is not an anonymous struct.

Comment: Thanks; that's the perfect explanation!  I'll reference it in my radar report :)

Comment: it is now defined as: struct CLLocationCoordinate2D {
 CLLocationDegrees latitude;
 CLLocationDegrees longitude;
};
typedef struct CLLocationCoordinate2D CLLocationCoordinate2D; so I guess @encode is broken.

Answer (score 4):

To get around this limitation until the bug is fixed, simply break down the coordinates and reconstruct:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSNumber *latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.coordinate.longitude];
    [coder encodeObject:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
    [coder encodeObject:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];
    ...

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[(NSNumber*)[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = (CLLocationDegrees)[(NSNumber*)[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D) { latitude, longitude };
    ...
```

Comment: Almost 9 years later this is, sadly, still necessary, and it still works

Answer (score 0):

It's because `@encode` chokes on CLLocationCoordinate2D

`NSLog(@"coords %@; type: %s", coords, @encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D));` yields `coords (
    "<00000000 00405e40 00000000 00804440>"
); type: {?=dd}`

Comment: okay, that's interesting.  so @encode gets that it's a structure with two doubles but misses the type name.  How come?  And really, why does the typename matter for an encoded struct?

Comment: I think the encode generates a string that's used to do something like `[[NSClassFromString(@encode(name)) alloc] init]` or some similar black magic to find the function that generates `CLLocationCoord` or `NSPoint` or whatnot.